# Get the size of xtick/ytick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to get the *size* of xtick/ytick labels (the `xtick.labelsize` or `ytick.labelsize` in a [`matplotlibrc`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) file).

I've looked around the [API of `axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels) but there's apparently no method for doing this.

Can this be done?

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong, but couldn't you access `mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']` for this?

Comment: @DavidWierichsyou are not wrong, that is precisely what I needed, thank you! Would you like to turn your comment into a full answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the current matplotlibrc file, use `matplotlib.rcParams` which is a dictionary containing the corresponding settings. For example:

```
xtick_labelsize = matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']
```